# Vim substitute highlight colors

Tags: vim, neovim

When using `:%s/foo/bar/c` to replace foo with bar, but with the c tag to have a yes or no dialog for each replace, I have really unreadable highlighting. All occurences of the searched word appear in grey background with white text (normal search highlight). However the one occurence I'm asked for is "highlighted" in yellow text without background => easily confused with regular text.

I found a million highlight search coloring things, but nothing to this one subsitute entry you are asked for. How do I change only this one? Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `IncSearch`.

From `:h hl-IncSearch` :

```
                                                        *hl-IncSearch*
IncSearch       'incsearch' highlighting; also used for the text replaced with
                ":s///c"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the thing. I didn't find it in :h myself, since it's kind of hard to search for something you don't know within so many groups and things. Cheers